# How to use child process with file args without writing to disk at nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to convert a received image (POST req with binary buffer) using a child process of "imagemagick" and send the result back (again, as binary buffer).
The imagemagick command requires filenames e.g

```
"convert input_file output_file"
```

It feels like a waste to save the incoming image to the disk, convert, and then read the output file from the disk to send it back. lots a disk IO ops..
What is the best way to do everything in RAM?

UPDATE:
I got one great answer, but it would be great if i can keep the access to the child process logs that come out of the stdout.

Comment: You can always create a RAM disk as temporary folder and use that

Comment: It should be noted though that with node.js a real disk I/O will lead to higher performance (throughput) than using RAM. This is because RAM access is synchronous and will block your server thus severely degrade performance (I'm saying like not by halving your server speed but more like reducing it by 90%)

Answer (score 1):

The `convert` command can take input from `stdin` and output to `stdout` (depending on your operating system). To use it, replace the file name with `-`, so:

`convert ${your options} -`

Then use node's child_process spawn to get the input stream to write to it and the output stream to read from it. E.g:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
const child = spawn('convert ${your options} - ')
child.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => { /* append output chunk */ })
child.stdout.on('end', () => { /* Do something with the result */ })
child.stderr.on('data' (chunk) => { console.log('Failed: ', chunk) }
child.stdin.write(buffer)
```

See examples at: https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php .

Comment: is there a way i can do as you suggested and also obtain the convert logs?

Comment: I would assume that there are no logs in this case, since stdout is used for the image data. All errors should be however reported in stderr.

Comment: the regular way of using it is "convert input_file output_file". so the logs goes to the stdout and the output goes to "output_file"